# Appending a list to a list in a loop (Python)

Tags: python, list, append

I have a Python list with values, say:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

I want to append in a loop a new list 'b' to the  list 'a'.

```
b = [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
```

The result should look like (when adding 'b' once to 'a'):

```
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]]
```

Now, I want to append the list `b` N times to the list `a`.
Both `a` and `b` have shape `(4,3)`
The result should then have shape: `(N+1,4,3)`

How do I do this?

Comment: One thing to remember is that lists are mutable. For your usecase, is it OK if the list is literally `[a, b, b, b]`? (In that, if I were to do `b[1][3] = "PASTA"` later in the code, is it OK that that propagates itself into your resulting array? (eg `array[2][1][3]` would give `"PASTA"`)

Comment: you probably want an numpy.array, not a native Python list!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native Python Lists will *not* behave the way you expect here as described in a few comments, so if you can use a 3rd party library, consider [NumPy](https://numpy.org/install/), which will behave more like a matrix of values as you expect and can then be converted back into a Python List

##### Setup

```py
>>> a = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
```

##### Replicate `b` vertically

- the second argument to `np.tile()` describes the replications in each dimension
- `.reshape()` to prepare it as a 3-dimensional array

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b_tiled = np.tile(np.array(b), (4,1)).reshape(4,4,3)
>>> b_tiled
array([[[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]]])
```

##### Collect `a` and `b_tiled` into the same array

NOTE `a` should be reshaped or `[a]` to match the shape of `b_tiled`

```py
>>> np.vstack((np.array([a]), b_tiled))
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 1],
        [4, 1, 0],
        [2, 1, 1]]])
```

##### `.tolist()`

You can use `.tolist()` to make a native Python list again, though it may be more convenient to you as a numpy array

```py
>>> np.vstack((np.array([a]), b_tiled)).tolist()
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]], [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]]
```

Comment: looks cleaner and since you have to import a library anway e.g. copy, its the better solution. The only downside I see is that numpy is much heavier than copy, e. g. for the unlikely case you want to create an executable. Anyway, propably best solution!

Comment: Since `np.array()` makes a proper copy of its input, you could also shorten the code to `np.array([a]+[b]*5)`.

Comment: Careful, your answer has shape (20,3) instead of (5,4,3) as I believe OP wants.

Comment: that's probably most clean as it took me a moment trying to figure out a comfortable way to get what they _appear_ to want

Comment: @joanis another reshape will correct that!

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping up my contributions to this discussion into an actual answer, summarizing what I think are the two best solutions:

### 1 Using NumPy arrays

Start from @Andreas' solution, but follow @ti7's lead and wrap the results into a numpy array, which manages the memory correctly:

```
result = np.array([a] + [b] * 5)
```

This solution brings the results into much more usable and versatile NumPy arrays.

### 2 Using deepcopy

Start from @Andreas' solution, and add a deep copy so the result does not alias parts of the array together:

```
import copy
result = [a] + [copy.deepcopy(b) for _ in range(5)]
```

This solution keeps the results as standard Python lists of lists.

Kuddos to @ti7 for noticing that the deep copy had to be done by instance of `b` rather than over the results, since `deepcopy` does not break aliasing that is internal to its input; and to @Andreas for assembling this line of code from the comments.

Caveat: since `a` is not deep copied here, `result[0]` is an alias for `a`, and changes to either will change both. Deep copy `a` too to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

add the lists and multiply the second list:

```
l = [a] + [b]*5

[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]]
```

---

In case you want to modify the list values later on, be aware that you actually have 5x the SAME list referenced *(as mentioned by **@ti7**)*, this means if you change one value in list b you change all, like this:

```
l[1][1][1] = "foo"

[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 'foo', 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 'foo', 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 'foo', 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 'foo', 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
[[2, 1, 0], [3, 'foo', 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]
```

---

to avoid that use *(as mentioned by **@joanis**)*:

```
l = [a] + [copy.deepcopy(b) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: this doesn't directly work because many of the members refer to the same member! try it yourself `c = [a] + [b]*5` `c[1][1][1] = "foo"`

Comment: In order to protect the results from have shared references, I would use `copy.deepcopy`: `import copy`, `c = copy.deepcopy([a] + [b]*5)`

Comment: @ti7 and joanis updated the answer accordingly to your comments. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: it needs to be done for _each_ copy (specifically the list multiplication is troublesome)

Comment: @joanis unfortunately this will not work, as ti7 pointed out you have to deep copy every list seperately, as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: @ti7 Good catch, thanks! I have to say I actually prefer your numpy array solution because numpy manages storage in a more intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

`[a+b*5]` this will create

`[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1],  [4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1]]]`